# extracting various structured data from hashref

Tags: perl

I have a hash, into which error messages are collected.
In the hash,  `__errlist__` is a key and then there is list of one value, which can be string, hash or nested hash like can be seen below:

String:

```
{'_errlist_' => ['Empty table error - data load failed.']}
```

Hash:

```
 { '_errlist_' => [
     {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column DWH_TENANT_ID not found in Q. (SQL-HY000) '}]}
```

Nested hash:

```
{'_errlist_' => [
     {'message' => 
         {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000) '}}]}
```

or:

```
{'_errlist_' => [
    {'message' => 
         {'message' => 
             {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000) '
                        }}}]}
```

What I came up with is:

```
 if (defined($RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'}->{'message'}->{'message'})){
  $errmsg = $RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'}->{'message'}->{'message'};
} elsif (defined($RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0])){
  $errmsg = $RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0];
} elsif (defined($RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'}->{'message'})){
  $errmsg = $RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'}->{'message'};
} elsif (defined($RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'})  ){
  $errmsg = $RunActSeq->[0]->{'_errlist_'}->[0]->{'message'};
} else {
  $errmsg = "Undefined Error";
}
```

But I'm still not getting the messages when extracting error messages strings, most of the time I get `HASH(0x3c04250)` not the message text.

Does anybody pls know how to extract error message more accurately?

Comment: When you check a higher level inside a Perl data structure, you can inadvertently create the lower levels. This is called [Autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).

Comment: Also, this "hash that collects error messages" doesn't seem to be too well designed. Perhaps it is the creation of that hash that should be fixed, not the reading of it.

Comment: @TLP thank you for your  notes, you're right about the design, it's all part of some old solution I'm not allowed much to change

Comment: This will illustrate autovivification: `perl -MData::Dumper -e'defined $foo{x}{y}{z}; print Dumper \%foo;'` Just by checking defined-ness of a hash key, you create the sublevels. Which you do in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a recursive lookup like this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my @tests = (
        ['Empty table error - data load failed.'],

        [ {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column DWH_TENANT_ID not found in Q. (SQL-HY000) '}],

        [ {'message' =>
           {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000) '}}],

        [{'message' =>
          {'message' =>
           {'message' => 'Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000) ' }}}],
    );

    for my $i (0..$#tests) {
        my $test = $tests[$i];
        my $hash = { "_errlist_" => $test };
        my $errmsg = extract_err( $hash->{_errlist_}[0] );
        say "Test #$i: $errmsg";
    }
}

sub extract_err {
    my ( $hash ) = @_;

    if (ref $hash eq "HASH") {
        return extract_err( $hash->{message} );
    }
    elsif (!(ref $hash)) {
        return $hash;
    }
    else {
        die "Unexpected reference type: ", ref $hash, "\n";
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Test #0: Empty table error - data load failed.
Test #1: Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column DWH_TENANT_ID not found in Q. (SQL-HY000) 
Test #2: Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000) 
Test #3: Prepare failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column not found . (SQL-HY000)
```

Comment: thank you @Håkon Hægland, one more question please, how should I modify it to extract `sql_stmt` from `'_errlist_' => [ 
    { 
     'message' => { 
        'message' => { 
                      'sql_stmt' => ' select * from db.table', 
                      'message' => 'Execute failed: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-2631)Transaction ABORTed due to Deadlock. (SQL-40001)' 
                      } 
                    } 
              } 
       ] `

Comment: Hi JanFi86. I am not sure exactly what you mean. Do you want to extract both the message and the sql statement? In the string you show there is an sql statement at level 3 nesting. Can there be `sql_stmt` on other levels? What will then be the expected output?

Comment: what I did was that I added `type` as input for the function, which could be `message` or `sql_stmt`. SO I would like to define what I'm searching in the end `message` or `sql_stmt`. `sql_stmt` should be on the 3rd level.

Comment: If you know the sql statement will always be on 3rd level, you could try something like [this](https://pastebin.com/AtcjCzWJ)